# Issue with conditional statement on external python file

Tags: python, python-3.6, file.readalllines

I created this script that could be used as a login, and then created an external text file that has the data `1234` in it, this is attempting to compare the data from the file, but outputs that the two values are different, even though they are the same.  Thanks In advance to any help you can give me, the code I used is below:

```
getUsrName = input("Enter username: ")
file = open("documents/pytho/login/cdat.txt", "r")
lines = file.readlines()
recievedUsrName = lines[1]
file.close()
print(getUsrName)
print(recievedUsrName)
if recievedUsrName == getUsrName:
    print("hello")
elif getUsrName != recievedUsrName:
    print("bye")
else:
```

Comment: you want to read the second line in the file with `lines[1]`?
or the first with `lines[0]`?

Comment: @0TTT0 I actually have a first line, I want to read the second line, I just simplified it for the description.

Comment: you have to add the exact content of the text file and the output of your script when you execute it.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like:

```
if recievedUsrName.strip() == getUsrName:
    ...
```

It must be the trailing newline.

Comment: I tried that just now, and it just gives the value for `else` (which I forgot to include on the code above,)

Comment: Can you print `lines[1]`?